# error callback function is fired even if request is successful

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script that uses ajax to send mail. I have tested it by checking the email that will receive the mail and true enough, the ajax request is successful. I also checked the console window of my Firefox browser and it also shows me a successful message. But my problem here is that instead of the `done` callback function, the `error` callback function is fired. You may all wonder why I'm still using the `error` function instead of `fail`. The reason for this is because when I tried using the `fail` function, it doesn't trigger the alertbox that I have set inside it. So what I did is go back and use `error` function again since at least it triggers the alertbox I made.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var submitButton = $('#submit');              // Variable to cache button element
    var alertBox1 = $('.success');                 // Variable to cache meter element
    var alertBox2 = $('.alert');
    var closeButton1 = $('.close1');                  // Variable to cache close button element
    var closeButton2 = $('.close2');                  // Variable to cache close button element

    $( function(){
        $( '#contactform' ).submit( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log( 'hello' );
            var formData = $( this ).serialize();
            console.log( formData );

            $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'send.php',
                 data: formData,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 done: function(){

                        $(submitButton).fadeOut(500); // Fades out submit button when it's clicked
                        setTimeout(function() { // Delays the next effect
                             $(alertBox1).fadeIn(500); // Fades in success alert
                        }, 500);
                 },
                 error: function(){
                    $(submitButton).fadeOut(500); // Fades out submit button when it's clicked
                        setTimeout(function() { // Delays the next effect
                             $(alertBox2).fadeIn(500); // Fades in fail alert
                        }, 500);
                 }
            });
        });

        $(closeButton1).click(function() { // Initiates the reset function
            $(alertBox1).fadeOut(500); // Fades out success message
            setTimeout(function() { // Delays the next effect
                $('input, textarea').not('input[type=submit]').val(''); // Resets the input fields
                $(submitButton).fadeIn(500); // Fades back in the submit button
            }, 500);

                return false; // This stops the success alert from being removed as we just want to hide it
        });

        $(closeButton2).click(function() { // Initiates the reset function
            $(alertBox2).fadeOut(500); // Fades out success message
            setTimeout(function() { // Delays the next effect
                $('input, textarea').not('input[type=submit]').val(''); // Resets the input fields
                $(submitButton).fadeIn(500); // Fades back in the submit button
            }, 500);

                return false; // This stops the fail alert from being removed as we just want to hide it
        });
    });
</script>
```

What seems to be the one causing this? Just to reiterate, I've tried using `fail` instead of `error` callback function since that is one of the answers I found in the Internet and also because I know for a fact that the `error` function is already deprecated. But because of the reason I mentioned above, I've no choice but to use it.

Comment: are you returning any json from the server?

Comment: try using success instead of done

Comment: i have never seen the "done" term being applied for a successful callback, as @Ritikesh says, rather try using "success" to attach the callback

Comment: if u set dataType: 'json' your server have to response guilty json or you allways went in the error callback

Comment: also which jquery version you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you refer the documentation, you cannot use done inside the ajax function as a callback. Either use success or add done at the end of ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
   // url, data etc
success: function() {
    //success handler
},
error:function(){
   //Error handler
}
});

     (OR)
$.ajax({
      // ajax related codes
}).done(function(){
     //callback
});
```

Also if you aren't really returning JSON from the server, remove the `dataType: 'json',` from the ajax call.